# Sugar CRM - How to add Custom Module to Navigation Bar shortcut?

Tags: module, sugarcrm

I created a new custom module Customer.
It is currently shown as a shortcut in ALL sections on the main page.
I want users to be able to select Customer when they mouse over the Sales shortcut (to show Customer next to Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities).

How do I add it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add modules to different menu groups from the page `Administration > Configure Module Menu Filters`. It will be in the section `Developer Tools` on the Administration page.